# How to add space to root partition / from non-adjacent ones

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am running out of space on sda5 root partition. I just wanted to install mariaDB, and I ran out of space. 
This is an HP machine that came with Windows 10, but I was fed up with it deciding when to reboot. So that gave me the courage to move on to Linux/Ubuntu, in a dual boot setup.
I partitioned the disk as was suggested elsewhere, by function... and then I just guessed partition sizes, and left big chunks for data (in sda3 and sda8). So my question is how can I make space for a couple of big packages on root?

- If by resizing/moving partitions, which steps to reduce 100G from sda3 and add to sda5
- If by ingeniously installing the packages elsewhere with a symbolic link, how
- Or something else

[GParted screen capture for my HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYorT.png)
Crucially (I think) from the image, I have 12 partitions:

```
sda#  mount (label)  size  unused
1 /boot/efi       260M  158M
2 msft reserved   16M
3 Windows         461G  117G
4 /boot           500M  356M
5 /               20G   1.96G
6 /home           18G   3.25G
7 swap            16G   11G
8 NTFS data       397G  236G
-unallocated-     1M
9 Windows RE tool 980M  570M
10 RECOVERY       17G   2G
-unallocated-     5M
```

Comment: Look into `mount --bind` Might be something there for you.

Comment: @StephenBoston wow, this is like a dream come true. would you suggest I partition sda3 into my new partition where i `bind mount` my installation of new packages? Is there anything else I should be aware of (it seems too simple a solution)?

Comment: It is something to look into. I don't want to advise beyond that. For me:  I would save my data and repartition the whole Linux side. Installation of applications doesn't take as long as we think. What does `df -h` show us? I've run into trouble like this when putting home to a separate partition. The idea is that you can update your system and keep your home but yeah no. One big partition is the way to go, particularly now with  SSDs.